# Why are 9 g of hydrogen 4.5 mol?

Tags: gas-laws

> A gas mixture consisting of $\pu{14 g}$ nitrogen ($\ce{N2}$) and
>   $\pu{9g}$ hydrogen ($\ce{H2}$) is in a closed vessel exerting a
>   pressure of $\pu{1.0 atm}$. The nitrogen and hydrogen partial pressures
>   exerted on the walls of this vessel are respectively?

We know that $\pu{14 g}$ of nitrogen is $\pu{0.5 mol}$ and $\pu{9 g}$ of hydrogen are $\pu{4.5 mol}$.

We have a total of $\pu{5 mol}$ and a pressure of $\pu{1 atm}$:

\begin{align}
\pu{5 mol} &\mathop{\hat{=}} \pu{1 atm}\\
\pu{0.5}   &\mathop{\hat{=}}\\
x &= \pu{0.1 atm}.
\end{align}

I wonder why $\pu{9 g} = \pu{4.5 mol}$?

Comment: Wait, didn't you just say _"We know that 14 g of nitrogen is half mol and 9 grams of hydrogen is 4.5 moles"_?

Comment: @IvanNeretin This is a resolution I found on the internet. Have another solution?

Comment: Why bother with another when this one is good?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There exists an equation that you must know: 
$$n = \frac{m}{M}.$$

Here $n$ is the amount of substance of a given sample of pure product, $m$ is the mass of the same sample, and $M$ is the molar mass of the pure substance.
Here, your sample has a weight equal to $\pu{9 g}$. The molar mass of $\ce{H2}$ is $2\times \pu{1 g/mol} = \pu{2 g/mol}$. So the amount of substance in the sample is: $$n = \frac{m}{M} = \frac{\pu{9 g}}{ \pu{2 g mol-1}} = \pu{4.5 mol}$$

Comment: I have removed the deprecated term "number of moles" and substituted the proper [amount of substance](http://goldbook.iupac.org/A00297.html) as you have also used that in your post.